# How to run a TCL script in Python?

Tags: python, tcl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Know any creative ways to interface Python with Tcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004434/know-any-creative-ways-to-interface-python-with-tcl)

In python , I need to put some values as input into a TCL script, let it run, then use its outputs.
how should I do that?

thanks

Comment: Try the solution on this page it should do what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004434/know-any-creative-ways-to-interface-python-with-tcl

Comment: thanks, I already saw that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) Python module.

Comment: there is a TCL script that I need change some of its parameters through python, let it run, then get its output

Comment: subprocess can just run a shell I guess

Comment: and that shell can run a tcl script, by calling the tcl interpreter and passing the tcl script to it

Comment: How about Tkinter?! I saw many links bringing it up for this!