# how to use TCL packages/code in python pytest program

Tags: python, tcl, pytest

I have been using TCL code, but i want use my all TCL packages/code in python pytest. Is it possible? If yes please let me know the process to accomplish this task.

Thanks

Malli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have python and need to run Tcl code, the easy way is to use Python's `tkinter` module, which is a wrapper around Tcl/Tk.

See the basic examples at https://wiki.python.org/moin/How%20Tkinter%20can%20exploit%20Tcl/Tk%20extensions

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.tk.eval('source {foo.tcl}')
root.tk.eval('foo_bar')
```

there are some parts that can be a little tricky, like moving data between those two, but if you mostly just call a few procedures, it works quite well.

Depending on how flow control works in your python scripts, you might not be able to use event loop related code (`fileevent`, `after`, etc.) without some changes like calling tkinters mainloop.

You can find some more exotic options in the answers to [Know any creative ways to interface Python with Tcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004434/know-any-creative-ways-to-interface-python-with-tcl)