# Need to run TCL script from python server

Tags: python, frameworks, tcl

I need to run TCL script from python server which uses framework written in Python. TCL scripts uses a framework written in TCL. So is there a way where i can integrate TCL framework to python framework and execute my scripts.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004434/know-any-creative-ways-to-interface-python-with-tcl

Comment: Can you be more specific? On the basis of what you've said so far, it could be anything from trivial to incredibly difficult…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Tkinter is what you are looking for.

If you have a file of Tcl code in a file called foo.tcl and you want to call the Tcl function foo_bar then:

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.tk.eval('source {foo.tcl}')
root.tk.eval('foo_bar')
```

I'd take a look into it:

- [How Tkinter can exploit Tcl/Tk extensions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/How%20Tkinter%20can%20exploit%20Tcl/Tk%20extensions)